# What is the correct javascript RegEx formula for removing trailing commas on a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this in a message forum, I don't know regex so I was hoping you could explain it to me or give me a better solution.

```
StrippedPrefix_JS_ItemNo = StrippedPrefix_JS_ItemNo.replace(/,$/,'');
```

What is the opening `/` for?

`$` is end of line, I know that much, and I can see the empty replace `''`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/,$/
```

the `/expression goes here/` is how javascript can define a regular expression. Without the `/`:

```
var expression =  ,$;
```

That's a syntax error. So the slashes mark it as an expression. It can also be written, `var expression = new RegExp(",$");`.

More Info about [**JavaScript RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Oh I see, the expression your looking for goes between the slashes.

Comment: While /,$/ works for some ',$' worked for me.  Thanks for the post.

I wish all JS were the same but unfortunately I've gone through 5 different variations of this script and finally this worked for me.  This seems to be typical for the software I am using :/